# keras fine-tuning a pre-trained model does not change weights when using multi_gpu_model and layers.trainable = True

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multi-gpu

I'm loading the VGG16 pretrained model, adding a couple of dense layers and fine tuning the last 5 layers of the base VGG16. I'm training my model on mutliple gpus. I saved the model before and after training. The weights are the same inspite of having layers.trainable = True.

Please help!

Heres the code

```
    from keras import applications
    from keras import Model
    <import other relevant Keras layers, etc.>


    model = applications.VGG16(weights = "imagenet", include_top = False, input_shape = (224,224,3))

    model.save('./before_training')

    for layer in model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    for layer in model.layers[-5:]:
        layer.trainable = True

     x = model.output
     x = Flatten()(x)
     x = Dense(1024, activation = "relu")(x)
     x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
     x = Dense(1024, activation = "relu")(x)
     predictions = Dense(2, activation = "softmax")(x)
     model_final = Model(input = model.input, output = predictions)


     from keras.utils import multi_gpu_model
     parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(model_final, gpus = 4)
     parallel_model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy" ..... )


     datagen = ImageDataGenerator(....)


     early = EarlyStopping(...)

     train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir,...)
     validation_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(test_data_dir,...)

     parallel_model.fit_generator(train_generator, validation_data = valiudation_generator,...)

     model_final.save('./after_training)
```

Weights in before_training and after_training models are the same!!! Which is not what I expected!

Comment: Ok, I took another look at the weights matrix and it looks like it has indeed changed a little bit. The change in weights was too small and I didn't notice it when I took a cursory glance. Sorry about that!

Comment: Is your question answered?

Comment: @unholy_me: It seems to be...